# Silent Printing on specific web pages from Chrome/Edge

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-applications, microsoft-edge

I’m aware of the `—-kiosk-printing` flag for Chrome, which I would be happy to use, but I only want silent printing on specific web pages.

(I know Firefox also has a setting but really only need for Chrome/Edge, working in Firefox would be a bonus.)

It’s really for a specific PDF, when I click a button on a specific web page. I don’t want to change the setting universally in the browser.

Is there a way to apply the `—-kiosk-printing` flag only to specific URL patterns?

I don’t believe there’s any way to toggle the flag from the web application code, but if there is, I’d be happy to hear it.

Are there any other ways of doing silent printing in Chrome/Edge?

Answer (score 1):

Here, I am assuming that you are using the **MS Edge Chromium** browser. I try to refer to the documents and also make tests with `--kiosk-printing` and `--disable-print-preview` command-line switches.

Based on my test result, the effect of the command line switches gets applied to the whole browser. I searched but did not get any information to apply it for specific web pages.

It looks like it is also not possible to toggle the flag from the web application code.

If you think that this feature should be added to the MS Edge browser, I suggest you press the `ALT + SHIFT + I` key in the MS Edge browser and try to provide your feedback there.

Thanks for your understanding.